# How to display properties in a DataGrid within a DataGrid with Cailburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

Im'm trying to present 2 DataGrids as details for a selected row in a enclosing DataGrid. The ViewModel has aside of a couple of string properties two lists which should be displayed if a row is selected. Upon selecting a row in the `StdMolecules` DataGrid the row details should be displayed. The Row details in the ViewModel are called `Molecules` and `Elements` and are set once a row is selected to the molecules and elements of the `SelectedMolecule` which is a `MoleculeModel`.

The ViewModel looks like this (boilplate is omitted for brevity)

```
public class MoleculeManagementViewModel : Screen
{
   :
   :
   public int Id {...}    // all properties with backingfields and Notify
   public string Name {...}
   public string MolecularFormula {...}

   public BindableCollection<MoleculeModel> Molecules {...}
   public BindableCollection<ElementModel> Elements {...}

   public BindableCollection<MoleculeModel> StdMolecules {...}

   public MoleculeModel SelectedMolecule {...}
   :
   :
}
```

The `MoleculeModel` and the `ElementModel` are as follows

```
public class MoleculeModel
{
   public int Id {..}
   public int Name {..}
   public int MolecularFormula {..}

   public List<MoleculeModel> Molecules {...} // every molecule may have other molecules as building blocks
   public List<ElementModel> Elements {...} // elements forming a molecule
}

public class ElementModel
{
   public int Id {..}
   public int Name {..}
   public int Symbol {..}
}
```

I have used the the following XAML to present the data structure within a Page-Object. I have only tried to display the `Id` property of the `Molecuels` list since once the mechnism is understood the other will follow.

But I have not managed to make it happen. :-(

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <DataGrid x:Name="StdMolecules" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMolecule}" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strukturfomel" Binding="{Binding MolecularFormula}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                        <!-- Constituent Molecule Grid -->
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <DataGrid x:Name="Molecules" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                      CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
         <!-- I try to display the 'Id' property of each molecule in the 'Molecules' in the ViewModel -->
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding MoleculeModel.Id}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strukturformel"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- Constituent Element Grid -->
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <DataGrid x:Name="Elements" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                      CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Symbol"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I have tried a number of different ways to display the `Id` of a molecule and none succeeded.

I would be greatful if I could get a hint how to do it correct.

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `cal:Bind.Model` attached property to the `MoleculeModel`:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="Molecules" cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                        //...
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I tried it and the data grid is showin the detail data grid but the detail data grid is not displaying any information - just blank cells. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Thank you indeed, your hint got me on the right track. Once I added the `cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"` I just needed to change the data grid text column binding, e.g. for `MoleculeModel.Id`, to `Binding="{Binding=Id}"` and it worked like a charm! Cool! :-)

Comment: @mph: Of course you shouldn't include MoleculeModel in the binding path. I edited my answer.